# Clear Cache after removing controller

Tags: caching, laravel-4

This is quite weird problem that i am facing. I had written the below code in index function of my controller

```
die(Hass:make('test'));
```

I wrote the spelling of `Hash` function wrong by mistake that generated the below error

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Hass' not found","file":"\/var\/www\/html\/app\/controllers\/admin\/BoardsController.php","line":12}}
```

After that i corrected the spelling of Hash function, but i am still getting the same error. Even, i removed that code from my controller but don't know why this error is still showing. After that i removed that controller file from the server but still getting same error. I run command `php artisan cache:clear` but still no success.

I also removed all cache files from /app/storage/views but still getting the same error. Please suggest.

Note: I am getting the data through ajax.

This is my Laravel error log:

```
[2015-03-10 18:06:56] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'Hass' not found' in /var/www/html/app/controllers/admin/BoardsController.php:12
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
```

Comment: did you check in the entire project if `Hass` doesnt occur anymore ?

Comment: This error is coming for only that particular controller file in which i am pulling data via Ajay request. As i stated above that i removed that controller file then still getting the same error. I check that Hass does not occur in entire source code.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're changes don't get applied on the server, or you're modifying the wrong file. Are you really sure you corrected the code *on the server*?

Comment: I agree with @lukasgeiter, you're probably not changing the correct file. Are you working with Homestead, or any other Vagrant box? If so, did you check if the files are syncing? Tell a little about your project settings: are you working locally, or via FTP, or with Homestead, VPN or what?

Comment: I am uploading files via FTP client by syncing folders of local and server. Even i removed the file from server then still getting that error.

Comment: @neeraj Do other changes get applied correctly? Create a new controller and route to test that.

Comment: well i am now going to upload entire source code again to get out of this. But thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a misspelling at your scope operator.

Try **`Hash::make()`** instead of `Hash:make()`.

Note the *double* `::` vs the *single* `:` that you put

Comment: I have even removed that controller script but still getting that error. This is something weird.

Comment: If you have removed the controller and is still getting the same error, then you're not editing the correct file, otherwise you'd be getting a different error at least. Perhaps your AJAX requests are being sent to somewhere else. Check your network logs (e.g. on Chrome's developer tools) and what is the URL you are posting to/getting from.